# Connect two different values with vertical line in highcharts

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

Hi I'm looking for a good chart plugin for my website. I found highcharts, which solves the mostly of my needs. Now I builded follow chart with this plugin:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Connect Values'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Value 1 and Value 2'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['24.05.2015', '01.06.2015', '12.06.2015', '19.06.2015', '25.06.2015'],
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Value 1',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Value 2',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Value 2',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [77, 69, 89, 84, 86],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Value 1',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [120, 118, 126, 129, 135],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Now I would like to connect the two values in a zone of the two different lines with a vertical line from point to point like this:

[image]

Or is this also possible:

[image]

Can I do this in highcharts? Or is there an other chart plugin which also contains multiple y-axis (2 or more) and can connect values? I hope for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the spline series with columnrange and poitnWidth param: http://jsfiddle.net/e9aqyzqa/

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan this is exactly the solution I searched for - thanks! You can put it in an answer, so I will mark it as correct answer if you want. Cheers.

Comment: wait, so you're connecting the two series that are plotting two different measures, on two different scales?  Sorry to put it so bluntly, but that's a terrible idea. If you have two different scales, the "connection" between the two points is completely meaningless, and can be manipulated to show whatever you want by adjusting the two scales differently.

Comment: Hi @jlbriggs no you are wrong: In our solution this is very importent and a requirement of our clients. We are searching for a chart for medical results of measured blood pressure. And there you have two different scales (systolic and diastolic), which have different value ranges (sys for example 100 - 200 and dia 70 - 90). You have to put them on different scales and still show, which belonging together. And you have to show the single value of sys, the single value of dia and the values of both together in a tooltip of the diagramm. This is for doctors very importent, for us it's strange...

Comment: @jlbriggs and they searched exactly a chart like my second picture in the question and also like the chart in the snippet of my answer. This shows the medical staff the correct chart of an measured blood pressure...For them, that is logical. But at the moment we just search for a good plugin which can generate such a chart. Highcharts is very good in that...We're looking forward to buy it perhaps..I hope you understand it a little bit better now.. :) Cheers.

Comment: fair enough. I'll have to read up plotting blood pressure. thanks for the info.

Comment: @jlbriggs Developing webv applications for hospitals or medical staff is mostly really confusing, because the "normal" human/user does'nt see the logic behind a medical requirement, but for them it's simply normal. :) I mostly feel like you now and I often need explications, why something is like this...Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the spline series in combination with columnrange type. Then set the  [pointWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.columnrange.pointWidth) param to declare size of each column:

```
    series: [{
        type:'columnrange',
        pointWidth: 2,
        data: [[5,10],[4,5],[10,20],[12,15],[15,19]]
    },{
        data: [10,5,20,15,19]
    }, {
        data: [5,4,10,12,15]
    }]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/e9aqyzqa

Comment: Thanks! Please look the image in my edited question: Is it also possible to remove the lines between the horizontal lines and just show the value points and the vertical line like in the picture? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me fine:

```js
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart:{
                    type: "spline",
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Blutdruck',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Amacher Hugo | 15.08.1977 (M)',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['25.05.2015', '28.05.2015', '01.06.2015', '07.06.2015', '12.06.2015']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Blutdruck mmHg'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mmHg'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'sys/dia',
                 type:'columnrange',
                    pointWidth: 2,
                    data: [[121,80],[124,95],[141,100],[122,85],[125,99]],
                },{
                    name: 'systolisch',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    data: [121,124,141,122,125],
                    marker : {
                        enabled : true,
                        radius : 5,
                        symbol: 'triangle-down'
                    },
                }, {
                    name: 'diastolisch',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    data: [80,95,100,85,99],
                    lineColor: null,
                    marker : {
                        enabled : true,
                        radius : 5,
                        symbol: 'triangle'
                    },
                }]
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

With the `lineWidth : 0` on my series it removed it. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 2):

On the same lines, you can try [Bar Chart with Connectors](https://jsfiddle.net/ashutosh_srivastav/7u29wLvc/)

```
$(function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: true
    },

    series: [{
      data: [10, 20, 40, 10]
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        [0, 10],
        [1, 20]
      ],
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      showInLegend: false
    }]
  }, function(chart) {
    var series = chart.series[0],
      data = series.data,
      xAxis = series.xAxis,
      yAxis = series.yAxis;
    chart.renderer.text().attr({
      zIndex: 10,
      align: 'center'
    }).add();
  });

  $('#button').click(function () {
    chart.series[1].setData([[2, 40],[3, 10]]);
 });
});
```